# How to remove all style and JavaScript and include new one in wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, enqueue

I am working on a legacy wp theme and have some lovely clean new CSS and js I want to apply to set template.

I have managed to remove old CSS and js from being applied to my new template using the script below.

However, how can I add new script and style to these functions whilst removing old?

For example, remove all old CSS and js now add these js and CSS

```
    /**
 * Remove all java scripts.
 */
function se_remove_all_scripts() {
    global $wp_scripts;
    if ( is_page_template( 'new-template/page-main.php' ) ) {
        $wp_scripts->queue = array();
    }
}

/**
 * Remove all style sheets.
 */
function se_remove_all_styles() {
    global $wp_styles;
    if ( is_page_template( 'new-template/page-main.php' ) ) {
        $wp_styles->queue = array();
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'se_remove_all_styles', 99 );

add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'se_remove_all_scripts', 99 );
```

Comment: Just a note, not at all an answer and not sure if you are aware of this, I see in one of the comments in your code `remove all java scripts` - There is a fundamental difference between Java and JavaScript. JavaScript is _not_ Scripts of Java, it is it's own thing entirely

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton of course good spot, thanks

Comment: Note that your solution probably removes all CSS & JS files from plugins as well which might cause some issues/break stuff. I'd use [wp_dequeue_style()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style) and [wp_dequeue_script()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script()) to remove theme's stylesheets & JS scripts only instead.

Comment: perfect, just trying this now, thanks @cabrerahector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can omit the legacy styles and scripts from enqueue function and create a new one for conditional queueing in your `functions.php` file. See this:

```
function my_conditional_enqueue() {
    if ( is_page_template( 'new-template/page-main.php' ) {
        /** Call your new style and script files */
    } else {
        /** Call legacy files */
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_conditional_enqueue' );
```